# how can i exceed time in my ansible playbook execution

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

i am executing the play book using command module 
when i ran command manually tha command will execute 20 minitues same command i am execute ansible playbook i am getting the ssh session time out error how can i over comet this error

```
ansible-playbook -i hots test.yml -T 1500

ansible-playbook -i hots test.yml --timeout 1500
```

```
tasks:
  - name: executing the command
    command: -------------
    retries: 30
```

i have tried shell or command to execution of playbook

```
tasks:
  - name: executing the create foldr
    command: echo "hi"
  - name: executing the command
    command: -------------
    retries: 30
```

how can i set the time period to execution of my play book 3o minitues

or completion command execution

in my playbook i have run a multiple command modules in my play book all are in simple execution but one command module is taking the time to execution of the command

Answer (score 1):

You should look for `async` and `poll` option.

```
- name: executing the command
  command: "-------------"
  async: 30
  poll: 0
```

Also you can refer [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) option if your requirement is to pause the playbook or wait for some specific condition

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to play with this parameter:

```
    # SSH timeout
    #timeout = 10
```

in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Answer (score 0):

For long running tasks, it's advised to make it async such that you aren't holding the ssh connection open and aren't partial to timeouts from the network or otherwise. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html